# Xamarin Android, read a simple text file from internal storage/Download

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin, and according to previous answers, this shall work:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "families.txt");
File.WriteAllText(path, "Write this text into a file!");
```

But it doesn't, I get and unhandled exception. I have set the permissions to read and write to external storage (even though this is internal).

I also tried it with this:

```
string content;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"file://" + path )) // with and without file://
{
    content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But I got the same unhandled exception.

---

**UPDATE:** The path is the problem, since I get the else part here:

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
if (file.CanRead())
    testText.Text = "The file is there";
else
    testText.Text = "The file is NOT there\n" + path;
```

Which is weird, because the path seems to be correct. The exceptions: Could not find a part of the path: /Download/families.txt

---

**UPDATE2:** On external storage, it works, with the same code... Might it be my device's problem? That would be great, cause I tested the external storage version on my friend's phone, but mine doesn't have external storage (OnePlus One), so I'm still looking for a solution (if there's any).

Comment: what is the specific exception you are getting?

Comment: If you use the "Break" option it should let you examine the Exception object to determine what the specific error causing it is.

Comment: can you log the path?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Try wrapping your File.WriteAllText in a try/catch(Exception ex) block and writing the ex.Message to the console.

Comment: Alright, updated it with the exception's message

Comment: Please make sure to avoid bad words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Finally found a solution.**

```
var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var filename = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "myfile.txt");
```

The path was the problem, now with a simple streamwriter it works like magic.

```
try
{
      using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
      {
             streamWriter.WriteLine("I am working!");
      }
}
catch { ... }
```

Comment: Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory has been deprecated....

Comment: this is a more than 7 year old question...